# Issue while connecting rJava in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, rjava

I installed the rJava package but it's showing the following issue while using the library

> library("rJava")
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
>     Reason: image not found

Comment: Share your machine's sessionInfo() !

Comment: for ubuntu , run it via apt-get - "sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava".

Comment: It macOS Sierra Versio 10.12.6 (16G29)

Comment: You aren't alone, this is a common problem on macOS. You need to run the following in R: `dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')`. You'll have to actually go to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` to determine what your exact version of the `.jdk` is, but that always works for me. You can put this in your `.Rprofile` to be loaded at startup if you use `rJava` often. Edit: to give credit where it is due, this is the original source: http://charlotte-ngs.github.io/2016/01/MacOsXrJavaProblem.html

Comment: Getting this error or running the follwing command in R: 
  dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
Error in dyn.load("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Hosme/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib") : 
  unable to load shared object .Further, jdk are : 1.6.0.jdk, jdk-9.0.1.jdk, jdk1.8.0_151.jdk '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 6): image not found

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/