# Installing rJava and xlsx in R Studio running on Mac OSX

Tags: r, xlsx, rjava

I am trying to install "xlsx" library in my R studio. But since I was not having "rJava" installed, the installation didn't go through.

No when I am trying to install "rJava" after installing jdk in my mac, still I am getting the same error while installation, below is the error for both the libraries.

```
"Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found"

"Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting rJava to be recognised seems to be a bit tricky. It looks as though R might be trying to look for it in the wrong place, in which case you could try the solutions to the similar question [Error of java path on loading rJava package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30572258/10923234) or the comments on [Issue while connecting rJava in R Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47133253/10923234)

Depending on what you need the xlsx library for, the tidyverse series of packages have packages for reading and writing xlsx files which are not dependent on Java, see [here](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/)